# classType parameter in RegisterClassHandler

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the purpose of the classType parameter:

```
public static void RegisterClassHandler(Type classType, RoutedEvent routedEvent, Delegate handler);
```

From msdn: "The type of the class that is declaring class handling."

But that still seems a bit of vague.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(MyClass), Button.ClickEvent, ClickHandler);
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Button), Button.ClickEvent, ClickHandler);
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(MyClass), Mouse.MouseDownEvent, MouseDownHandler);
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Button), Mouse.MouseDownEvent, MouseDownHandler);

    }

}
```

I suppose the first handler comes closest to the class *declaring* the handler. But adding a second handler on the button also seems to work? What is right way to do this? Also a for the Mouse.MouseDownEvent it is possible to add a handler on a button in a completely unrelated class?

Comment: If it isn't obvious, there is an example on the MSDN page.

Comment: @Clemens Could you please add a link.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597875(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Comment: Yes from that I should use the MyClass. But what about the Button types? Is it completely wrong or is there any purpose for it? Can i use it  like an attached eventhandler on all instances of a button?

Comment: Not sure, I'd say the intended usage is to pass the type of the class where you call RegisterClassHandler. Maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling

Answer (score 0):

The classType parameter in RegisterClassHandler is used to invoke the classhandler when an instance of the classType (or derivedType) is on the route of a RoutedEvent.

For example ButtonBase.ClickEvent is handled on the Window instance in the following code:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), ButtonBase.ClickEvent, Handler);
```

Which would be like adding (attaching) a handler on every Window element:

```
<Window ButtonBase.Click="Handler">
```

So classType doesn't necessary have to be the class containing the code to register the handler.

The sender in the handler then is an instance of classType.